# Unable to set TagBuilder InnerHtml Property to some value?

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1

I have noticed that TagBuilder InnerHtml Property has been changed in ASP.NET Core 3.1. It does not have 
the set for `InnerHtml` property anymore. So when I try to do this:

```
TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a");
tag.InnerHtml = "Hello";
```

I get the error as:

> **Property or indexer 'TagBuilder.InnerHtml' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only**

I checked that in ASP.NET MVC the same code was working correctly. How to achieve -`tag.InnerHtml = "Hello";` to work in asp.net core 3.1.

Comment: `TagBuilder.InnerHtml` is writable neither in [ASP.NET Core 2.1](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v2.1.16/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/Rendering/TagBuilder.cs#L60), [nor in 2.0](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/2.0.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/Rendering/TagBuilder.cs#L60) and [not even in 1.1](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/1.1.8/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/Rendering/TagBuilder.cs#L60). Are you sure this is what you have been doing before?

Comment: @poke I checked it once more. It was writable in MVC 5 but not in Core. So the above code worked in ASP.NET MVC 5.

Comment: Okay, solutions in ASP.NET MVC are not compatible to ASP.NET Core. So you will have to look for a different approach here.